# Magento Go, referencing a JS file attached to a theme in a CMS static block?

Tags: javascript, magento

If I want to reference a JS file in a CMS block and the js file has been attached to the theme, how is it done? The CMS block has the script:

```
<script>
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
Galleria.run('#galleria');</script>
```

I dont have the functionality to see where the JS are stored once they are loaded into the JS editor and library section of Magento Go.

I would omit the section but it needs to be there, so should look like:

```
<script>
Galleria.loadTheme('JS file attached to the theme');
Galleria.run('#galleria');</script>
```

Can someone enlighten me as to the location of the JS files and how to add it?

Comment: This question is probably going to be a better fit over at http://magento.stackexchange.com - public launch in a few day.

Comment: Moved onto the other site now so this can be closed now.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/483/magento-go-changing-theme-css-to-view-media-storage-image